# Does this antenna break Chu's limit?

Tags: antenna, bandwidth

I ran into this antenna datasheet and found it interesting.

https://www.johansontechnology.com/datasheets/0433AT62A0020/0433AT62A0020.pdf

From my understanding, the return loss graph on page3 shows the bandwidth for 433MHz (wavelength=0.69m) is around 10%.

Size of this antenna is 25 * 5 * 1.2mm. Since a sphere of radius of 1.25cm can encompass the antenna, it is technically a small antenna. Chu limit states Q >= 1 / (2 * pi / 0.69 * 0.125) + 1 / (2 * pi / 0.69 * 0.125) ** 3 = 686.86. Then bandwidth <= 1 / Q = 0.0015 << 10%.

Am I missing something or they break the limit and how?

Comment: As a monopole, the counterpoise (ground plane) cannot be ignored here. Also RL need not be the radiation bandwidth, though it's probably close here so I don't have a strong issue with that.

Comment: There are several mistakes here: the calculation is the minimum Q, the first inequality is backwards; and, the numbers shown give a value of 1.557, but it seems were calculated correctly regardless as 12.5mm and 0.69λ give 686.86.  Adding a link to the Wiki article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chu%E2%80%93Harrington_limit seems worthwhile.

Comment: Hmm, I take that back.  The reported gain is -4dBi at best, whereas a dipole is ideally 2.15dBi; evidently they're discarding 75% of the incident power, so the input return loss can be quite a bit worse; this implies, I think, for a simple network, the Q measured at the port must be at least 4x lower. But this is getting to degrees of quantitative understanding of antennas I lack, so I'll let others fill in from here.

Comment: @Tim, you are right about the first inequality being backwards and I corrected it. It was my typo and thanks for pointing it out. The following calculation about max bandwidth still holds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have pointed out, it is not just the SMD component that forms the antenna, it is that plus the attached groundplane / PCB.  Chu's sphere has to enclose both.  Find the smallest structure that radiates before you try to apply the limit.  You can assume an infinitesimal RF generator.

The gain is only specified over about a 5% bandwidth, so the Q is somewhat higher than you suggest.

This antenna has a dipole like pattern, so the directivity is around 2dBi, hence the specified typical gain of -4dBi represents a loss of around 6dB. This allows a lot of scope to increase the bandwidth from the Chu limit (if necessary) at the expense of return loss.  Check out the Fano matching limit.

When the antenna is significantly lossy, the measured return loss may not have as much to do with the radiation bandwidth of the antenna as you think.  As an example, put a 6dB attenuator in series with a half-wave dipole, and you have better then 10dB return loss over an enormous bandwidth.  If you measured that bandwidth at the -10dB points, you would probably violate Chu's limit as well.

Answer (score 1):

There's some mistake in your math.

$$\begin{aligned}
a &= 0.125{\rm\,m} \\
\lambda &= 0.69{\rm\,m}  \\
k &= 2\pi/\lambda = 2\pi/0.69=9.11 \\
Q &\ge \frac{1}{k a} + \frac{1}{k^3 a^3} \\
Q &\ge 1.56 \\
\end{aligned}$$

Now, since \$Q = f_c/(f_2-f_1) =f_c/(f_c \cdot BW) = 1/{BW}\$, where \$BW\$ is relative bandwidth, we have

$$\begin{aligned}
1/{BW}\ge1.56.
\end{aligned}$$

Given BW=10%=0.1, we have

$$\begin{aligned}
1/0.1 &\ge 1.56 \\
10 &\ge 1.56. \\
\end{aligned}$$

So, as far as Harrington limit is concerned, that antenna isn't even close to it :)

Comment: 12.5mm = 1.25cm = 0.125dm = 0.0125m.

Comment: There's a mistake in the first line. a = 0.0125m.